# In the Postfix main.cf file which FQDN is assigned to mydestination?

Tags: postfix, email-server

**Environment:** Postfix 3.3, Dovecot 2.2, Centos 8, Digital Ocean Droplet

**Background:** Inside `/etc/postfix/main.cf` is the following directive.

```
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
```

When I look up `$myhostname` I get the following definition:

> The myhostname parameter specifies the internet hostname of this
>   mail system. The default is to use the fully-qualified domain name
>   from gethostname(). $myhostname is used as a default value for many
>   other configuration parameters.

The contents of `/etc/hosts` includes this line,

```
127.0.0.1 server.example.com server
```

However in my A and AAAA DNS records my mail server is `mail.example.com`.  My MX record is slightly different,

```
Type: MX

Hostname: example.com

Value: mail.example.com
```

**Question 1:** In this instance is my FQDN `mail.example.com`, `server.example.com` or something completely different?

This is where I get confused and I'm not sure how to confirm it one way or the other.

**Question 2:** In my MX record is my Hostname `example.com` correct or should it be `server` or `server.example.com` like it is in my `hosts` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re talking about couple of things that are not directly related. Your hosts file really doesn’t mean anything here. It’s contents don’t come in to play and is irrelevant in your questions.

> In this instance is my FQDN mail.example.com, server.example.com or
>   something completely different?

What do you want it to be? In this case, it appears you want to know what `$myhostname` will equal. It will be whatever FQDN you configured the server with. Use the `hostname` command to check or change it. Based on the rest of your info, it should be `mail.example.com` and your `/etc/hosts` file should reflect that but, again, it has no role here. Your server can have multiple DNS names but only one hostname. The hosts file is just a way for your server to find itself or other servers and override DNS.

> In my MX record is my Hostname example.com correct or should it be
>   server or server.example.com like it is in my hosts file?

The `hostname` field is the domain your email addresses are at. Based on your info it should be `example.com`. I.e. johndoe@example.com will be delivered to the server with the hostname (value) `mail.example.com`. Honestly, I’m not really sure what the hostname setting is there for. MX records always exist within the context of the domain where they are configured. It is unnecessary, and not possible, to specify a different domain name in a MX record. This is something specific to your hosting provider.

On a side note, remember you will be unable to reliably deliver email unless you also setup a PTR record with your ISP or hosting provider for the public IP address of your server that also points to `mail.example.com`. This record exists with the owner of the IP, which is not you or your DNS servers.